# Why does space in Bash string subscripts matter here?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm experimenting with bash scripting and noticed the following behavior:

```
file="test.jar"
echo "${file: -4}" #prints .jar
echo "${file:-4}"  #prints test.jar
```

Very confusing behavior actually. Can someone explain why the second case prints the whole `test.jar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to inconsistent syntax. `{"string":-}`  means default (all the string), whatever follows `-`. So you need either a space or parenthesis:

```
{"string": -4}
{"string":(-4)}
```

Read [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is a compromise due to the timeline of features being added to Bash.

- The `${parameter:-word}` or `${parameter-word}` syntax for "replace *`parameter`* with *`word`* if *`parameter`* is null or unset (`:-`) / null (`-`)" was around for pretty much always; the `-` version was already in the [Version 7 Bourne Shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/).
- The `${parameter:offset:length}` and `${parameter:offset}` syntax for "substring of *`parameter`* starting at *`offset`* (with optional length *`length`*)" was introduced in Bash 2.0 (no conflict so far).
- Negative offsets and length specifications for the substring construct were introduced in Bash 4.2. This leads to a problem:

  ```
  $ string=01234567890abcdefgh
  $ echo ${string:7:-2}           # Not ambiguous
  7890abcdef
  $ echo ${string:-7}             # Interpreted as "undefined/null, or..."
  01234567890abcdefgh
  $ echo ${string: -7}            # Interpreted as offset from the end
  bcdefgh
  $ echo ${string:(-7)}           # Interpreted as offset from the end
  bcdefgh
  ```

The space before `-` or the parentheses around the negative offset are there to tell the expansion apart from the `:-` (default value) expansion.

If the space is not there, the expansion `${file:-4}` is interpreted as "print `4` if the parameter `file` is null or unset, and the expansion of `file` otherwise".

References:

- [BashFAQ/061: Is there a list of which features were added to specific releases (versions) of Bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061)
- [Bash hackers wiki: Bash changes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges)
- [Shell parameter expansion in the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- [Bash NEWS file describing feature added per version](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)